# Flex accessing custom component's children properties

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.5, mxml

Is there a way to access children's properties of a custom components from mxml and not from the actionscript.

For example, i have a component "A"

```
<s:Group>
   <mx:UIComponent id='childA'/>
   <mx:UIComponent id='childB'/>
</s:Group>
```

And somewhere in the application i want to do something like this

```
<s:HGroup>
   <components:A>
      /*I want to access properties of this children objects*/
      <childA width="20"/>
      <childB color="0xFFFFFF"/>
   </components:A>

   <components:A>
      /*And here too*/
      <childA width="60"/>
      <childB color="0x000000"/>
   </components:A>
</s:HGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in ActionScript; but not in MXML.  In ActionScript:

```
componentAInstance.childA.width = 20;
componentAInstance.childB.setStyle('color',0xFFFFFF);
```

This is what we call a horrible break in encapsulation; becahse the "parent" should not need to know about the implementation details of its children.

ComponentA should know how to size and position its own children; in this chase childA and childB.  It should not need help from ComponentA's parent.

You may find benefit in reading this blog post about how [component's should communicate with each other](http://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2013/2/1/How-does-one-Flex-Component-talk-to-another-Flex-Component).

Comment: Yeah, but i was wondering about mxml-way. The thing is: i've got specific loader component which has more than 4 parameters of it's appearance and some component which contains that loader. This component could occupy entire screen of the application or could be 32 by 32 pixels. I was thinking about controling loader appearance from the mxml without getting into much customization from the code. I guess i've got to pass this properties through the container component now.

Comment: @Komlev why not make these 4 parameters properties of the parent object. When set, and if the children exist, it can apply the properties to the children.

Comment: This is an extra work, i know it is minimal but it is there, i was wondering is there a way to make is without alternating parent class. I was hoping mxml could give me some "syntactic sugar".

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean my suggested answer is extra work or if @SunilD. comment is.   SunilD's approach is the correct one from an speculation perspective.